# Where is merged distributed keras / tensorflow final model saved?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, distributed-tensorflow

Excuse me . I have a question . I'm working with a distributed version of tensorflow and keras and I succeeded to make a sample deep learning network work on multiple programs (python scripts) working together but I don't know how to save final single model on one of hosts while currently each script is saving it's own model as checkpoint separately.
Thanks.

Source code I used to develop my program :

[Distributed tensorflow / keras code sample on github](https://gist.github.com/fchollet/2c9b029f505d94e6b8cd7f8a5e244a4e)

For example in the source code above , final model save path is not set , would you tell me how to set it ?

Comment: Welcome. Your request seems waaaaay  to broad and it's highly unlikely that will attract interest. You might want to rephrase your question and be as detailed as possible

Comment: @amonk hi , thanks . Would you help me to rephrase my question . I mean what details should I add to my question because this is my first question .
Thanks .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I mean instead of mentioning github path and 124 lines of code, try to focus on a particular issue of the code . Welcome again